# Using BFS/DFS to solve programming task

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am currently trying out Task #2 in the 2016/2017 COCI. Although I have attempted to solve this problem, I couldn't do it.

So, I looked at the solution and it said,

> In order to solve this task, we need to find any path Barry can take
>   from the initial position to any position in the last column. We can
>   do this by using BFS or DFS algorithm, after which we need to
>   construct the path. Finally, all that’s left is to format the path
>   according to the task.

So I went ahead and studied the BFS and DFS algorithm. However, I am not sure how I can implement this algorithm into my program.

Although I can find certain elements in a tree with the algorithm, I don't know how to use it to find a pathway.

So can someone tell my, briefly, how to use the BFS/DFS algorithm to solve the programming problem?

Thanks in advance.

This is the contest page:
http://hsin.hr/coci/archive/2016_2017/contest1_tasks.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is convert the whole map into a tree.
Here is a diagram I made to demonstrate what I exactly mean:[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX4j4.jpg)

Hope that made sense.

Comment: Thank you!! The diagram helped me lots to understand how to implement the BFS algorithm.